# Wordpress website is displaying incorrectly

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming

I still have this error in `myWebsite/wp-admin/` in spite of there is nothing wrong with the code "I guess"!
The Error is :

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at .../wp-content/themes/mh-magazine/functions.php:54) in /pages/..../wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1216

But what I have in this line is this code :

```
 ini_set( ‘upload_max_size’ , ’25MB’ );
 ini_set( ‘post_max_size’, ’27MB’);
 ini_set( ‘memory_limit’, ’30MB’ );
```

In addition to not displaying anything but the header of the website although all data is existent in my dashboard (When I was able to see content of my dashboard.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Output has already been sent, i.e. the HTML body, so you can't send HTTP headers anymore.

Usually this means you have `display_errors` on or something and it outputted a notice or a warning.

Turn it off! And check your `error_log` to see what the problem was.

Otherwise, check for unexpected white space before opening `<?php` tags, or echoes and var dumps.

Comment: from which file can i check my error_log ? and i have already checked the white spaces before and after the tags because i got the same problem with  wp-config.php as well but was solved through deleting some white spaces!
And here the line number doesn't direct me to the tags!

Comment: Problem is solved but still doesn't display all the content correctly although all the data is approachable through the dashboard and already published.

Comment: if you check `php_info()` you should see where your error_log is stored on the server